# Tomcat RemoteIpFilter configuration in web.xml vs server.xml

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, web.xml, server.xml

I had issue of setting RemoteIpFilter in web.xml: I put the following setting in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I sent request to the server with HTTPS header, there is no "Secure" flag.

But if I put

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
      remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
      protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
      protocolHeaderHttpsValue="https" />
```

in server.xml, the same request, I got "Secure" flag.

We prefer to set configuration in web.xml for each application. Don't know why it doesn't work in web.xml - I set it as indicated in tomcat configuration doc https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#Basic_configuration_to_handle_'x-forwarded-for'*and*'x-forwarded-proto

Anyone has any idea about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the XML:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>RemoteIpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteIpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>protocolHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>x-forwarded-proto</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: Tomcat [8.5.40](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.40_(markt)) (April 2019) introduced `X-Forwarded-Proto` as default value for the `protocolHeader` property, so the problem in this question no longer applies to recent versions of Tomcat.